# In protractor is it possible to use a spec under a spec?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've a login-spec.js like below:

```
describe('user should login with given credentials', function() {
 beforeEach(function() {
   browser.waitForAngular();
 });

 it('Get page title', function() {
   browser.driver.getTitle().then(function(text){console.log(text);});
   expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('abc','therefore Passed');
 });

it('login registered user', function() {

  loginpage.enterUsername('username');
  loginpage.enterPassword('password');
  loginpage.loginBtn().click();
  browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then
      (function(url) {
          return (/homepage/).test(url);
      });
    });
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(baseurl+'/homepage');
});
```

Now i want to do some action on the homepage, like say click on a web element. The code of homepage is in a different spec say homepage-spec.js

```
describe('homepage', function() {
     beforeEach(function() {
       browser.waitForAngular();
     });

     it('click guest list', function() {
       homepage.guestlist().click();
     });
```

Now would i be required to write the login page code and login the user in homepage spec? Would it be possible to call the login-spec.js code in homepage-spec.js and execute it? like when i give

```
protractor conf.js --suite homepage-spec.js
```

The browser opens with the login page and logs in displaying the homepage on which the displayed web element is clicked.

Comment: Look at pageobjects - http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects

Comment: @Grasshopper i did go through the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884479/protractor-how-to-reuse-the-same-spec-file-for-different-tests & http://ramt.in/how-to-run-identical-jasmine-specs-multiple-times-with-protractor/ before raising the question. They all are already saying the same thing as you indicated. But this is not the solution i was looking for. Seems like this should be raised as a feature request.

Comment: QA Evangelist, the behavior that you are describing is exactly what page objects are used for. There is no need to have one test **call** another test. You aren't asserting anything on the login. You just need a function that performs all the login actions for you. Look here for an example https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md

Comment: ok great! I was indeed using the page objects but only for defining web elements in them.. then passing the username and password variable values, clicking the login button in spec file, thereby reusing the same code in other homepage spec file too for loggging.. now as I understand it that the same code should be in the login PO file and then call the defined login functions in homepage spec.. and in anyspec where logging in is required..

Changing the username and password should be done in the login PO file.. now this is what I could have done in the spec file too.. what's the difference?